# Dell XPS 15 9530 (touchscreen) Always needs to hard restart

Tags: windows-10, freeze, bluetooth, hibernate

It is running windows 10. Whenever I shut it down (hibernate or normal shutdown). It needs to hard restart. That I need to push and hold the power button for few seconds, release and push again to start it. It has a bluetooth mouse connected. So everything opens newly. And no work is saved as in hibernate. Other than that it works just fine. I have clean installed the windows but still it has the problem. I think it's mostly bios or hardware issues?
Anyone had similar problems? Any solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this on a Samsung laptop and the issue was that the drive (SSD) was hardware encrypted. The sleep mode allowed it to wake without asking for the hardware decryption password, so it couldn't read the drive and had to reboot.